# How can I configure an interface based on altname with NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

In my nvidia orin nx I have NetworkManager to configure the internet connections. How can I configure an interface based on his altname?
The problem that I have to use the system with a USB Mobile modem and depending if its a cold boot or a restart the USB Mobile modem will create a eth1 or eth0 interface.
However I still need to assign a static IP address to the actual physical interface of my device and the only way that I identify it is by its altname

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:b0:2d:e9:c5:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enP8p1s0
    inet 192.168.1.69/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The question is more about how can I assign this enP8p1s0 interface a static IP that will persist across reboots and that it works even if I add the mobile modem and the enP8p1s0 is eth1 instead of eth0.

So far I've used a script on boot.

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.69/24 dev enP8p1s0;
```

But then it appears that when the interface looses connection it also its assigned IP so its not very robust. I was wondering if I could do something similar with NetworkManager configuration files.

Comment: You should be able to use a udev rule to assign the device a static name. See e.g. [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking#configuring-user-defined-network-interface-names-by-using-udev-rules_consistent-network-interface-device-naming).